# Having unexpected symbol error, but no obvious unexpected symbols

Tags: r

I'm getting the following error when I'm working on a data set

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "                     'T6145000',"
```

I am basically trying to rename a long list of variables. When I tried running the code with all names on the same line it would only read so far and then stop. I have therefore changed the code so that the list continues across multiple lines. The unexpected symbol error seems to be referring to the first name on the last line of names. There are no other symbols there other than 'T6145000','the next variable code', so I'm not really sure why this comma is registering as unexpected.

Here is my code, it is very long (nearly 9000 variables, listed over 10 lines) so I've tried to trim it somewhat

```
colnames(new_data) <- c('E8011201'...
                        ...'T6144900',
                        'T6145000','T6145100'...)
```

T6144900 is the last variable of the ninth line, and T6145000 is the beginning of the tenth.

The code was generated when the data was acquired so there shouldn't be typos, and certainly I cannot see one. The only thing I have done to the line is simply put different sections on different lines. I'm probably being daft but I can't see what is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a symbol that is not the correct `,`

Comment: Do you have an IDE that does syntax highlighting? What happens if you copy that single line of code into the R command line (define a dummy `new_data` object first)?

Comment: Hi, thanks. 

I did wonder that, and I changed the commas either side of the error but it is still happening. I also changed the apostrophes too just in case.

Comment: Hi Hong Ooi

I'm using RStudio. The code, when it was all in one line, was green so far and then black. I've broken the line up so that all parts are coloured green. (Hope that makes sense!)

As in, the proposed variable names are green. There aren't any warnings appearing in RStudio on the script.

Comment: Can you save the script in a file i.e. `yourfile.R` and `source('yourfile.R')`  I am guessing that this may be due to the line limit

Comment: I would have thought the error would be referencing where the problem is and that part seems to be ok. I would post the whole thing but it's far too big!

Yes the script saves without issue.

Comment: What about the `source`?  DId it showed any errors?

Comment: It didn't. And the column names appear to have changed. 

Thank you, not sure what the other error was about then

Comment: I tried a test run and I think that is the issue here.  `library(stringi);capture.output(dput(stri_rand_strings(9000,2)), file='file.txt')` and then tried to copy/paste the whole into the console.  It gives the same error as there is a line limit for copy/pasting.  So, it is better to save it in a file and then `source`

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your advice and help. 

New to R and didn't know about that at all, will look out for it in future.

Comment: No problem.  If you copy/paste small chunks, this will not be a problem.

Comment: "my code, it is very long (nearly 9000 variables, listed over 10 lines)" That's just crazy. Try to do some programming instead to achieve your goal.